# Prooving that a shift in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$ is a uniformly continuous transformation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a Lebesgue's measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let's define a shift for $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$ by the following formula
$$f_y(x) = f(x-y).$$

I am to show that for $p \in [1, \infty)$ the transformation
$$\mathbb{R}^d \ni x \mapsto f_y \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$$

is uniformly continuos.

I was able to  prove it for continuous functions defined on a compact support ($f \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$). Using [Lusin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) I know that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$.

How can I use this knowledge to prove it in $L_p$? Can I just create a sequence of functions from $C_c$?

Comment: is $x\mapsto f_y$ supposed to be $y\mapsto f_y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$

Let $g \in C_c$ such that $(\int |g-f|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} <\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Exists $\delta >0$ such that $(\int|g_x-g_y|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\forall x,y :|x-y|<\delta$

By Minkowski's inequality we have that and some changes of variable,we have that:

$\forall x,y:|x-y|<\delta$ 
$$(\int |f_y-f_x|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq (\int|f_y-g_y|)^{\frac{1}{p}} (\int |g_y-g_x|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}+(\int|g_x-g_x|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\epsilon$$

Comment: do we have triangle inequality without $p$th roots? I'm aware its true for $p\le 1$

Comment: @CalvinKhor you are right,i forgot to put the roots,..i edited. thank you for the correction.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thank you!